# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException caused while terminating the app

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, navigation

I have an app with 2 pages calendar.xaml(start page) and historystatistics.xaml. Error is thrown when I navigate to historystatistics and back to calendar and then try to terminate the app by the pulling down gesture. The mentioned error occurs at the SaveAsync function in OnSuspending of App.xaml.

```
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        CycleManager cycMan = CycleManager.Instance;
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        if (cycMan.Reset != true)
        {
            await Appname.Common.SuspensionManager.SaveAsync(); // **ERROR**
        }
        deferral.Complete();          
    }
```

It says

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> GetNavigationState doesn't support serialization of a parameter type
>   which was passed to Frame.Navigate.

Where did I wrong? I did a simple navigation from historystatistics page from xaml like this

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Are you passing a parameter to the navigation? Notice that you can only pass serializable objects.

Comment: Nope. No parameters are passed. I read in some forum that it can happen if i try to pass a complex parameter. I havent even written the goback function since it is the default Basic page and hence it contains the back button.

Comment: So try overrighting the goback function and try to pass an empty string.

Comment: @inxs base.GoBack(sender, e); ??

Comment: just a regular overwriting. `public void overwrite GoBack(sender, Eventargs)`

Comment: There must be definitly some point in your code where you try to pass a non-serializable property to the navigation.I had some similiar issue in silverlight, the problem occured at a totally different location but it was also due to a property which couldn't be serialized. Try searching for the point when you pass paramters to your navigation.

Comment: Making the method *async* just isn't appropriate.  You've got *one* shot at saving state, trying to do it asynchronously can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant Since Appname.Common.SuspensionManager.SaveAsync() is async, I had to make tht the function async

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SuspensionManager uses Frame.GetNavigationState() to get the history of the Frame. It then tries to serialize the navigation history to a string, unfortunately it has no way to know how to serialize custom complex types .

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate) :

> Note  The serialization format used by these methods is for internal
>   use only. Your app should not form any dependencies on it.
>   Additionally, this format supports serialization only for basic types
>   like string, char, numeric and GUID types.

The best solution for this problem to  rewrite the NavigationParameter or if you didn't want to save your app state just comment the line :

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //await SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```